# Wso2 DSS and SQL Server exec stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, wso2

When I put in the WSO2 query to perform a simple stored procedure (sp_xxx exec), an error  occurs when calling the service, but when I put a SQL SELECT it works normal. Does anyone know why?

This is the error log:

```
[2012-08-09 09:01:55,071] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet} -  
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.isClosed(DelegatingResultSet.java:688)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.isClosed(DelegatingResultSet.java:688)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery(SQLQuery.java:904)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.runQuery(SQLQuery.java:2071)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.execute(Query.java:252)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.execute(CallQuery.java:185)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQueryGroup.execute(CallQueryGroup.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.operation.Operation.execute(Operation.java:71)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:592)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:691)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:563)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:409)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: **WHAT** is that error?? We can't see your screen, nor can we examine your error log - you'll need to tell us the relevant bits so we might have a chance to help .....

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to successfully execute stored procedures with the WSO2 Data Services Server. Can you please post the error log (if there's any) printed on the console or in the DSS_HOME/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log when you came across the aforementioned issue?

Regards,
Prabath

Answer (score 0):

You issue is most probably the same thing as reported here: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-550. This has been fixed for the upcoming DSS 3.0.0 release. The reason for this is, you're using a JDBC3 driver, but in DSS 2.6.3, we use JDBC4 (Java6) features, so you should use a JDBC4 driver. But it seems, the only JDBC4 feature we specifically use so far (which can give problems for older drivers) is the ResultSet.isClosed, and we have put a workaround for this in the new release. The patch is there on the issue if you want to patch the data service core jar, or else, just try to use a JDBC4 driver.

Cheers,
Anjana.